# Azure Load Testing: How to upload the supportive CSV file for the load test?

Tags: azure, jmeter, azure-load-testing

I have created a test in Azure Load Testing using Azure CLI

> az group create --name sample-rg --location westus2
>
> az load create --name sample-resource --resource-group sample-rg
> --location westus2
>
> az load test create --test-id sample-test-id --load-test-resource
> sample-resource --resource-group sample-rg --display-name "Find IP"
> --description "Test description" --test-plan IPLoadTesting.jmx --engine-instances 1 --env rps=2 count=1

[image]

However how to upload the supportive CSV file for the load test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure Load Testing: How to upload the supportive CSV file for the load test?.

To upload `CSV` files to **Azure Load Test** using `PowerShell`.

To check the **Azure Load Test** Test IDs, you can use the following command.

```
 az load test list --load-test-resource "sampletestdemo" --resource-group ".Resource-Group-Name>"
```

**Output:**

[image]

To upload the **CSV** file to **Azure Load Test** using **PowerShell**.

```
az load test file upload --test-id "79113b24-2af3-41bb-xxxxxxx" --load-test-resource "sampletestdemo"  --resource-group "<RG-Name>" --path '/home/useradmin/Resourcegroupusage.csv'
```

**Output:**

[image]

Once ran the above script, the **CSV** file has been uploaded to **Azure Load Test** in the **Azure Portal**

[image]

Reference:  [az load test file upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/load/test/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az-load-test-file-upload)